# Google Play Service Mulitplayer Matchmaking

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer

I'm developing a multiplayer game for android using the google play services realtime mulitplayer api.

The documentation says its possible for other players to join a running game. I dont want players to join a running game. What i do want is a possibility to automatch 2,3 or 4 players. So currently i use:

```
RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minNumberOfOpponents, maxNumberOfOpponents, 0);
```

with min and max opponents set to 1 and 3.

If 2 players connected to the game the onRoomConnected callback is called, and i start my game, which is fine.

1. My question is, is this room closed for other players afterwards or is it possible for other clients to connect to this room after that? I would assume that room is fully connected and closed for other players , but cause the documentation says something about joining running games i'm not sure.
2. Also i give the players the option to only search for games with 3 opponents. In this case the device calls the autoMatchCritera with 3 and 3. Am i correct in the assumption, that if 4 clients search a game (three with 3,3, and one with 1,3) these players get connected as i intent it ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

1. If a room has been connected, no other peers are autojoined to this room.
2. If we have a 3 player game and 2 players search the game with 1,2 they are nearly instantly connected for a 2 player game. If one client searches with 2,2 and than the two other connect with 1,2 a 3 player game is started.